# Add products on local storage using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig, local-storage

I have a twig view where I display a catalog with products, I want to be able to save each product on localStorage when a user clicks ADD button. For now I can only get just the first product from one page. If I change the page and select another product the first one gets replaced. The products will eventually go in a cart and from there in the entity using a controller path. For now I want to make this part work.

The HTML+Twig code:

```
<div id="parentDiv"  class="product row">
                {% for products in pagination %}

                    <div class="product col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 hero-feature">

                      <div id="{{attribute(products ,'id')}}"  class="product thumbnail">

                        <img id="prodImage"  class="product img-responsive img-rounded" src="{{attribute(products ,'image')}}" style="width:150px;height:150px" >

                        <div class="caption">

                            <h4 id="prodPrice"  class="product pull-right"><b>{{ attribute (products, 'price') }}Lei</b></h4>

                            <h4 id="prodName" class="product"  style="height:100px;width:200px;">

                                <a id="prodLink" class="product"  
                                    href="{{ attribute (products, 'affiliatelink') }}" 
                                    target="_blank">{{attribute ( products, 'name') }}</br></a>

                            </h4>

                           </div>

                              <div class="add-to-cart" >

                                   <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Adauga</button>

                              </div>

                    </div>                         

                  </div>

                {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

And the jQuery code:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>                                            
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {     

               $('button').on('click', function(){


         var products =
                 {
                   prodID    :$('.thumbnail').attr("id"),
                   prodName  :$('#prodName').text(),
                   prodPrice :$('#prodPrice').text(),
                   prodImage :$('#prodImage').attr('src'),
                   prodLink  :$('#prodLink').attr('href')
                 };

                     localStorage.setItem('products', 

JSON.stringify(products));

var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
console.log('retrievedObject: ', retrievedObject);
         });

});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are uses same key for Storage ("products").You can use different key and maintain it.

Suppose your product ID is unique then use it.

e.g.
                     localStorage.setItem('products-1,JSON.stringify(products));

localStorage.setItem('products-2,JSON.stringify(products));
and so on

Refer below code

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {     
  var prodId = $('.thumbnail').attr("id");
               $('button').on('click', function(){


         var products =
                 {
                   prodID    :$('.thumbnail').attr("id"),
                   prodName  :$('#prodName').text(),
                   prodPrice :$('#prodPrice').text(),
                   prodImage :$('#prodImage').attr('src'),
                   prodLink  :$('#prodLink').attr('href')
                 };

                     localStorage.setItem('products-' + prodId, 

JSON.stringify(products));

var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products-' + prodId));
console.log('retrievedObject: ', retrievedObject);
         });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but that solved just one of the problems. The script only takes the first product on each page. If I click another product from the same page it only return the first one in console and the storage doesn't change. But now I have more values :). Maybe I am doing something wrong with my HTML part?

Comment: I will close the question and mark your answer as correct. Thank you.